# Insertar un vector en una matriz

Tags: java, array, bucles

quería pedir ayuda con un problema que estoy teniendo en este codigo, tengo una matriz donde esta almacenado los nombres de las provincia de mi pais, y por medio de una rutina que acepte el nombre de una provincia y un arreglo con la cantidad de hombres y mujeres, se debe de buscar la fila correspondiente en la matriz y agregar la informacion sobre cantidad de hombres y mujeres, el codigo esta corriendo, pero cuando se pide imprimir la matriz, no imprime la informacion sobre cantidad de hombres y mujeres

A continuacion les apunto el codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practicaSiete {

public static String[][] matrizProvincias = { { "San Jose", " ", " " }, { "Alajuela", " ", " " },
        { "Heredia", " ", " " }, { "Cartago", " ", " " }, { "Limon", " ", " " }, { "Puntarenas", " ", " " },
        { "Guanacaste", " ", " " } };
public static Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String[] infoPersonas = new String[2];


public static void agregarInformacion(String nombreProvincia, String[] cantidadPersonas) {
    int m = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrizProvincias.length; i++) {

        if (matrizProvincias[i][0].equals(nombreProvincia)) {

            for (int j = 0; j < matrizProvincias[i].length; j++) {
                matrizProvincias[i][j] = cantidadPersonas[m];
                m++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void imprimirMatriz(String[][] matriz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + "");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int m = 0; m < 7; m++) {
        System.out.print("Digite la provincia para agregar informacion: ");
        String nombre = leer.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < infoPersonas.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Agrege la cantidad de hombres y mujeres (en este orden): ");
            String cant = leer.next();
            infoPersonas[i] = cant;
        }
        agregarInformacion(nombre, infoPersonas);
    }
    imprimirMatriz(matrizProvincias);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
public static void imprimirMatriz(String[][] matriz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(matriz[i][0] + ": Hombres = " + matriz[i][1] + " | Mujeres = " + matriz[i][2]);
    }
}
```